# How do I automatically switch to the iOS custom keyboard when entering my app?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I would like when entering my app to automatically switch to my custom keyboard like the **Facemoji** app.
Is this possible to force user to open only custom keyboard without going into setting option. I want whenever user opens the app. only custom keyboard should open, not other. In my app there is preview function, show as extended keyboard otherwise it will show default keyboard i will fail.
thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make custom keyboard only for my app in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449741/how-to-make-custom-keyboard-only-for-my-app-in-swift)

Comment: This sounds like a UX nightmare waiting to happen; I would implore you to take a step back with your design and really understand *what* it is you're trying to solve for and whether restricting users to a single custom keyboard makes sense when balanced with the UX implications of doing so.

Comment: In my app there is 1 preview screen showing app features, if its not my extended keyboard my preview will fail

Comment: Didnt dig into this, but you would probably just have to build a custom UI that only exists in your app. Using the keyboard extension system would provide it to the user outside the app, and also if you ever use it with sensitive data, it defaults to the OS keyboard. Completely custom UI is the only solution off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` have property `inputView`
You can set any view you want inside yours application.
So you can use use the same view used for your's custom keyboard