# How to automatically select and change a custom keyboard on iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, object, mobile, keyboard

i already got list of installed custom keyboard using under code but how can i select specific custom keyboard.

```
[UITextInputMode activeInputModes];
```

I want to select my custom keyboard when open my app,But I haven't found a way to make the system automatically choose to use my keyboard.

I have tried the following methods, but none of them work,likes this:

```
[UITextInputMode setValue:@[myInputModel] forKey:@"activeInputModes"];
```

or

```
[UITextInputMode setValue:myInputModel forKey:@"currentInputMode"];
```

Comment: I found an App that can implement this function, which is "Fonts", but I don't know how it implements it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make custom keyboard only for my app in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449741/how-to-make-custom-keyboard-only-for-my-app-in-swift)

Comment: @lazarevzubov No, I want to change the global keyboard, not just within the app

Comment: Have you seen this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1924/_index.html?

Comment: @lazarevzubov I've looked at this, but just opening the settings, I want to be able to change the keyboard currently used by the system through code

Comment: The docs univocally say that it's impossible: 'iOS custom keyboard extensions can replace the iOS system keyboard with a custom keyboard for use in all apps. To enable a custom keyboard, an iOS user must open the Settings app and navigate to General > Keyboard > Keyboards > Add A New Keyboard.'

Comment: @lazarevzubov I found an App that can implement this function, which is "Fonts",

Comment: It's not true. I've checked the app, and it redirects you to Settings during onboarding.

Comment: @lazarevzubov  "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fonts/id1454061614 " Is this what you downloaded？

Comment: Yes, this one precisely.